# How to deal with None shape sizes in a custom layer whose output size should be half the input size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When writing a custom layer in Keras with the input of shape `(BatchSize, Height, Width, NumChannels)` it should output a shape of `(BatchSize, Height // 2, Width // 2, NumChannels)`, but I'm not sure how to handle the case when I get `BatchSize`, `Width` and `Height` == `None` because the layer is used on different inputs of varying size.

How to properly compute the output shape in that case in my layer ?

Comment: If you pass padding = "same" and strides = (1,1) for the Conv2D layer, then a MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)) can do it for you. It will truncate the dimensions for you.

Comment: But it must be possible to implement something like Conv2D from scratch without relying on the existing Conv2D functions. Let's say I want to write a custom layer which crops the central piece of half the size from the input. Somehow it must be possible to compute offset and size from the input shape, but I'm not sure how to handle it properly when it is initially called with "None" in some of its dimensions. :/